# how to filter API data Find the 15 most spoken?

Tags: javascript

Use the countries API to fetch data about countries. **strong text**

```
API_URL = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all'
```

Use the countries API to fetch data about countries.

How many languages are there in the countries API

Find the 15 most spoken languages

Comment: It sounds like a homework...

Comment: // data fetched from API
let data = allcountrydata
// array to store lang with stats
let lang = []

data.forEach(country => {
    for(let i = 0; i < country.languages.length; i++) {
        if(Object.keys(lang).indexOf(country.languages[i].name) == -1) lang[country.languages[i].name] = 1
        else lang[country.languages[i].name] += 1
    }
})

console.log(lang)
// [Punjabi: 2 ,Afrikaans: 2, Albanian: 3, Amharic: 1, Arabic: 25, Armenian: 2, Aymara: 1, Azerbaijani: 1, Belarusian: 1, Bengali: 1, Bislama: 1, Bosnian: 2.......] 
there are 112 different languages

Answer (score 1):

> // data fetched from API
> let data = allcountrydata
>
> // array to store lang with stats
> let lang = []
>
> data.forEach(country => {
> for(let i = 0; i < country.languages.length; i++) {
> if(Object.keys(lang).indexOf(country.languages[i].name) == -1)
> lang[country.languages[i].name] = 1
> else lang[country.languages[i].name] += 1
> }
> })
>
> console.log(lang) // [Punjabi: 2 ,Afrikaans: 2, Albanian: 3, Amharic:
> 1, Arabic: 25, Armenian: 2, Aymara: 1, Azerbaijani: 1, Belarusian: 1,
> Bengali: 1, Bislama: 1, Bosnian: 2.......]  there are 112 different
> languages

Answer (score 0):

The data for each country has a population value for the country and a list of languages spoken in the country.
However each language in the list does not seem to have a count of speakers, so unless that data is there, you cannot figure out the most spoken languages unless you assume that 100 % of the population of each country speaks all the languages spoken in the country - and that would be quite an assumption.

I think it is not possible to answer "15 most spoken languages" from the data provided in https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all